# Slick slider with readmore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a reviews widget using slick slider. Some reviews are long and I need to hide them and I am trying to use the readmore.js plugin for this. Everything works fine, before I decrease the resolution to the first breakpoint, after that when I press' "read more" button the page is moved to the top or if add "/" after "a href" in the code the page just remains in the same place.

Here is the slick slider part

```html
 <script src="https://assets.codepen.io/3490843/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://assets.codepen.io/3490843/readmore.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://assets.codepen.io/3490843/slick.min.js"></script>
    
 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

$('.multiple-items').slick({
   autoplaySpeed: 3000, 
  autoplay: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  
responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        adaptiveHeight: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
        });
  
  </script>
```

Readmore.js

```js
<script>
 $(function() { 
 $('.demo').readmore({ 
 moreLink: '<a href="#">Read more...</a>', 
 lessLink: '<a href="#">Hide</a>', 
 collapsedHeight: 56, 
 speed: 200, 
 afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) { 
 if(! expanded) { // The "Close" link was clicked 
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top}, {duration: 100}); 
 } 
 } 
 }); 
 });
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript:;` to the default action of the event (e.g. following a link)

```
moreLink: '<a href="javascript:;">Read more...</a>', 
lessLink: '<a href="javascript:;">Hide</a>',
```

OR

use jQuery ( Assuming you are using demo as a parent class )

```
$('.demo a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not help, unfortunately.